# Filter by Regex in JQ

Tags: json, regex, bash, command-line, jq

```
[{
  "Address": "The Sq"
 },
 {
  "Address": "1 Bridge Rd"
}]
```

With the following JSON, how do I write a script using JQ to filter for a regex where i want the result to be only Address's with numbers as the first character. I build this JSON using

```
map({ Address: .[].payload.address })
```

how do i add to this to filter for the regex expression I want (which is \A[0-9])

Answer (score 48, accepted):

If you tacked the following filter onto the one you already have, then you'd get the output shown below:

```
map(select(.Address | test("^[0-9]")))
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "Address": "1 Bridge Rd"
  }
]
```

For robustness, you might like to consider adding `?` after the test:

```
map(select(.Address | test("^[0-9]")?))
```

Or, you could combine the two calls to `map` in various ways. You might like to consider:

```
.[].payload.address | select(test("^[0-9]")?) | {Address: .}
```

Comment: Do you mean that i should be running `map({ Address: .[].payload.address })
| map(select(.Address | test("^[0-9]")))`?, i get an error for this: null (null) cannot be matched, as it is not a string

Comment: In your question, you indicated that the JSON was the output of the given `map` filter.  I have verified that if that is the case, the output is as shown.  Maybe it would help if you followed the mcve guidelines more closely: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Hey sorry for the confusion. I understand your answer and that one of them is building off the code I provided, but both solutions seem to throw me an error.

Comment: The updated answer has a suggestion you might find helpful.

Answer (score 6):

Though the accepted answer works, I find this more readable

```
$
$ echo '[{"Address": "The Sq", "n": 1}, {"Address": "1 Bridge Rd", "n": 2}]' | \
  jq '.[] | .Address | select(.|test("^[0-9]"))'

"1 Bridge Rd"
$
$ echo '[{"Address": "The Sq", "n": 1}, {"Address": "1 Bridge Rd", "n": 2}]' | \
  jq '.[] | select(.Address|test("^[0-9]"))'

{
  "Address": "1 Bridge Rd",
  "n": 2
}
$
```

If you want to do a little different filtering:

```
$ echo '[{"name": "john doe", "sex": "male", "age": 26, "occupation": "city planner", "cod": "asphyxiation"}, {"name": "jane doe", "sex": "male", "age": 24, "occupation": "beautician", "cod": "strangulation"}, {"name": "crispy lips", "sex": "male", "age": 38, "occupation": "convicted killer"} ]' > in.json
$ cat in.json | jq .
[
  {
    "name": "john doe",
    "sex": "male",
    "age": 26,
    "occupation": "city planner",
    "cod": "asphyxiation"
  },
  {
    "name": "jane doe",
    "sex": "male",
    "age": 24,
    "occupation": "beautician",
    "cod": "strangulation"
  },
  {
    "name": "crispy lips",
    "sex": "male",
    "age": 38,
    "occupation": "convicted killer"
  }
]
$
```

Then we can do basic regex-filter/transform like this:

```
$ cat in.json | jq '.[] | .name'
"john doe"
"jane doe"
"crispy lips"
$
$ cat in.json | jq '.[] | .name | select(.|test(".*doe"))'
"john doe"
"jane doe"
$
$ cat in.json | jq '.[] | select(.name|test(".*doe"))'
{
  "name": "john doe",
  "sex": "male",
  "age": 26,
  "occupation": "city planner",
  "cod": "asphyxiation"
}
{
  "name": "jane doe",
  "sex": "male",
  "age": 24,
  "occupation": "beautician",
  "cod": "strangulation"
}
$ 
$ cat in.json | jq '.[] | select(.name|test(".*doe")) | {n: .name, a: .age}'
{
  "n": "john doe",
  "a": 26
}
{
  "n": "jane doe",
  "a": 24
}
$ 
$
```

Comment: tried this answer - `error: test is not defined`

Comment: @Drey Tried last 2 just now, work for me. I have `jq-1.6` on Ubuntu. Can you post a reproducible example as a new question or here if it's small enough.

Comment: thanks for fast answer, it was old jq version, with 1.6 it works fine!